# Does $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+i}\right)$ tend to infinity or limited value?

Tags: calculus, limits

So, I discovered this limit problem originally with my friend:

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+i}\right)$$

I used Wolfram Mathematica and found it tend to be infinite, but the software didn't give a step-to-step solution, and I really couldn't find a solution after thinking about it for a long time.

Could someone help?

Comment: Do you know about harmonic numbers ?

Comment: Yes. The sum of the reciprocal of the first n natural numbers.

Comment: Rewrite $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+i}=\sum_{i=1}^{n+\sqrt n}\frac{1}{i}-\sum_{i=1}^{\sqrt n}\frac{1}{i}$$

Comment: Thank you, I have known how to proceed.

Comment: After that, use the asymptotics of $H_q$ twice and finish with Taylor

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to provide the simplest solution I have found so far.

Obviously we could prove that $x>\ln(x+1)$ when $x>0$,
build on this, we could have $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+i}
>\sum_{i=1}^{n}\ln(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+i})=\sum_{i=1}
^{n}\ln(\frac{\sqrt{n}+i+1}{\sqrt{n}+i})=\ln(\frac{\sqrt{n}+n+1}
{\sqrt{n}+1})=\ln(1+\frac{n}{\sqrt{n}+1})>\ln(1+\sqrt
{n}-1)=\frac{1}{2}\ln(n)$

Then the conclusion is trivial as $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2}
\ln(n)=\infty$.